# Nativescript + Angular : Could not build production app using AOT flag

Tags: angular, webpack, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm trying to build a production app using the nativescript 5.1.1 using aot flag but without success but if i remove the aot flag it works the code as expected .

im using nativescript 5.1.1 with angular with the webpack plugin .

**package.json**:

```
{
    "nativescript": {
        "id": "org.nativescript.xxxx",
        "tns-android": {
            "version": "5.1.0"
        },
        "tns-ios": {
            "version": "5.1.0"
        }
    },
    "description": "NativeScript Application",
    "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
    "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "~7.1.0",
        "@angular/common": "~7.1.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "~7.1.0",
        "@angular/core": "~7.1.0",
        "@angular/forms": "~7.1.0",
        "@angular/http": "~7.1.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.1.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.1.0",
        "@angular/router": "~7.1.0",
        "nativescript-angular": "~7.1.0",
        "nativescript-appavailability": "^1.3.1",
        "nativescript-drop-down": "^4.0.1",
        "nativescript-fresco": "^5.2.0",
        "nativescript-google-maps-sdk": "^2.6.1",
        "nativescript-loading-indicator": "^2.4.0",
        "nativescript-ngx-slides": "^6.1.0",
        "nativescript-sqlite": "^2.3.0",
        "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.4",
        "nativescript-toasty": "^1.2.0",
        "nativescript-ui-listview": "^5.1.0",
        "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.8",
        "rxjs": "~6.3.0",
        "tns-core-modules": "~5.1.0",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.1.0",
        "@nativescript/schematics": "~0.5.0",
        "@ngtools/webpack": "~7.1.0",
        "nativescript-dev-sass": "^1.6.0",
        "nativescript-dev-typescript": "~0.7.0",
        "nativescript-dev-webpack": "^0.19.0"
    },
    "readme": "NativeScript Application"
}
```

**webpack.config.js**:

```
const { join, relative, resolve, sep, dirname } = require("path");

const webpack = require("webpack");
const nsWebpack = require("nativescript-dev-webpack");
const nativescriptTarget = require("nativescript-dev-webpack/nativescript-target");
const { nsReplaceBootstrap } = require("nativescript-dev-webpack/transformers/ns-replace-bootstrap");
const { nsReplaceLazyLoader } = require("nativescript-dev-webpack/transformers/ns-replace-lazy-loader");
const { getMainModulePath } = require("nativescript-dev-webpack/utils/ast-utils");
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } = require("webpack-bundle-analyzer");
const { NativeScriptWorkerPlugin } = require("nativescript-worker-loader/NativeScriptWorkerPlugin");
const UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");
const { AngularCompilerPlugin } = require("@ngtools/webpack");

module.exports = env => {
    // Add your custom Activities, Services and other Android app components here.
    const appComponents = [
        "tns-core-modules/ui/frame",
        "tns-core-modules/ui/frame/activity",
    ];

    const platform = env && (env.android && "android" || env.ios && "ios");
    if (!platform) {
        throw new Error("You need to provide a target platform!");
    }

    const projectRoot = __dirname;

    // Default destination inside platforms/<platform>/...
    const dist = resolve(projectRoot, nsWebpack.getAppPath(platform, projectRoot));
    const appResourcesPlatformDir = platform === "android" ? "Android" : "iOS";

    const {
        // The 'appPath' and 'appResourcesPath' values are fetched from
        // the nsconfig.json configuration file
        // when bundling with `tns run android|ios --bundle`.
        appPath = "src",
        appResourcesPath = "App_Resources",

        // You can provide the following flags when running 'tns run android|ios'
        aot, // --env.aot
        snapshot, // --env.snapshot
        uglify, // --env.uglify
        report, // --env.report
        sourceMap, // --env.sourceMap
        hmr, // --env.hmr,
    } = env;
    env.externals = env.externals || [];
    const externals = (env.externals).map((e) => { // --env.externals
        return new RegExp(e + ".*");
    });

    const appFullPath = resolve(projectRoot, appPath);
    const appResourcesFullPath = resolve(projectRoot, appResourcesPath);

    const entryModule = `${nsWebpack.getEntryModule(appFullPath)}.ts`;
    const entryPath = `.${sep}${entryModule}`;
    const ngCompilerTransformers = [];
    const additionalLazyModuleResources = [];
    if (aot) {
        ngCompilerTransformers.push(nsReplaceBootstrap);
    }

    // when "@angular/core" is external, it's not included in the bundles. In this way, it will be used
    // directly from node_modules and the Angular modules loader won't be able to resolve the lazy routes
    // fixes https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/4024
    if (env.externals.indexOf("@angular/core") > -1) {
        const appModuleRelativePath = getMainModulePath(resolve(appFullPath, entryModule));
        if (appModuleRelativePath) {
            const appModuleFolderPath = dirname(resolve(appFullPath, appModuleRelativePath));
            // include the lazy loader inside app module
            ngCompilerTransformers.push(nsReplaceLazyLoader);
            // include the new lazy loader path in the allowed ones
            additionalLazyModuleResources.push(appModuleFolderPath);
        }
    }

    const ngCompilerPlugin = new AngularCompilerPlugin({
        hostReplacementPaths: nsWebpack.getResolver([platform, "tns"]),
        platformTransformers: ngCompilerTransformers.map(t => t(() => ngCompilerPlugin)),
        mainPath: resolve(appPath, entryModule),
        tsConfigPath: join(__dirname, "tsconfig.tns.json"),
        skipCodeGeneration: !aot,
        sourceMap: !!sourceMap,
        additionalLazyModuleResources: additionalLazyModuleResources
    });

    const config = {
        mode: uglify ? "production" : "development",
        context: appFullPath,
        externals,
        watchOptions: {
            ignored: [
                appResourcesFullPath,
                // Don't watch hidden files
                "**/.*",
            ]
        },
        target: nativescriptTarget,
        entry: {
            bundle: entryPath,
        },
        output: {
            pathinfo: false,
            path: dist,
            libraryTarget: "commonjs2",
            filename: "[name].js",
            globalObject: "global",
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: [".ts", ".js", ".scss", ".css"],
            // Resolve {N} system modules from tns-core-modules
            modules: [
                resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/tns-core-modules"),
                resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
                "node_modules/tns-core-modules",
                "node_modules",
            ],
            alias: {
                '~': appFullPath
            },
            symlinks: true
        },
        resolveLoader: {
            symlinks: false
        },
        node: {
            // Disable node shims that conflict with NativeScript
            "http": false,
            "timers": false,
            "setImmediate": false,
            "fs": "empty",
            "__dirname": false,
        },
        devtool: sourceMap ? "inline-source-map" : "none",
        optimization: {
            splitChunks: {
                cacheGroups: {
                    vendor: {
                        name: "vendor",
                        chunks: "all",
                        test: (module, chunks) => {
                            const moduleName = module.nameForCondition ? module.nameForCondition() : '';
                            return /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/.test(moduleName) ||
                                appComponents.some(comp => comp === moduleName);
                        },
                        enforce: true,
                    },
                }
            },
            minimize: !!uglify,
            minimizer: [
                new UglifyJsPlugin({
                    parallel: true,
                    cache: true,
                    uglifyOptions: {
                        output: {
                            comments: false,
                        },
                        compress: {
                            // The Android SBG has problems parsing the output
                            // when these options are enabled
                            'collapse_vars': platform !== "android",
                            sequences: platform !== "android",
                        }
                    }
                })
            ],
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: new RegExp(entryPath),
                    use: [
                        // Require all Android app components
                        platform === "android" && {
                            loader: "nativescript-dev-webpack/android-app-components-loader",
                            options: { modules: appComponents }
                        },

                        {
                            loader: "nativescript-dev-webpack/bundle-config-loader",
                            options: {
                                angular: true,
                                loadCss: !snapshot, // load the application css if in debug mode
                            }
                        },
                    ].filter(loader => !!loader)
                },

                { test: /\.html$|\.xml$/, use: "raw-loader" },

                // tns-core-modules reads the app.css and its imports using css-loader
                {
                    test: /[\/|\\]app\.css$/,
                    use: {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: { minimize: false, url: false },
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /[\/|\\]app\.scss$/,
                    use: [
                        { loader: "css-loader", options: { minimize: false, url: false } },
                        "sass-loader"
                    ]
                },

                // Angular components reference css files and their imports using raw-loader
                { test: /\.css$/, exclude: /[\/|\\]app\.css$/, use: "raw-loader" },
                { test: /\.scss$/, exclude: /[\/|\\]app\.scss$/, use: ["raw-loader", "resolve-url-loader", "sass-loader"] },

                {
                    test: /(?:\.ngfactory\.js|\.ngstyle\.js|\.ts)$/,
                    use: [
                        "nativescript-dev-webpack/moduleid-compat-loader",
                        "nativescript-dev-webpack/lazy-ngmodule-hot-loader",
                        "@ngtools/webpack",
                    ]
                },

                // Mark files inside `@angular/core` as using SystemJS style dynamic imports.
                // Removing this will cause deprecation warnings to appear.
                {
                    test: /[\/\\]@angular[\/\\]core[\/\\].+\.js$/,
                    parser: { system: true },
                },
            ],
        },
        plugins: [
            // Define useful constants like TNS_WEBPACK
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                "global.TNS_WEBPACK": "true",
                "process": undefined,
            }),
            // Remove all files from the out dir.
            new CleanWebpackPlugin([`${dist}/**/*`]),
            // Copy native app resources to out dir.
            new CopyWebpackPlugin([
                {
                    from: `${appResourcesFullPath}/${appResourcesPlatformDir}`,
                    to: `${dist}/App_Resources/${appResourcesPlatformDir}`,
                    context: projectRoot
                },
            ]),
            // Copy assets to out dir. Add your own globs as needed.
            new CopyWebpackPlugin([
                { from: { glob: "fonts/**" } },
                { from: { glob: "**/*.jpg" } },
                { from: { glob: "**/*.png" } },
            ], { ignore: [`${relative(appPath, appResourcesFullPath)}/**`] }),
            // Generate a bundle starter script and activate it in package.json
            new nsWebpack.GenerateBundleStarterPlugin([
                "./vendor",
                "./bundle",
            ]),
            // For instructions on how to set up workers with webpack
            // check out https://github.com/nativescript/worker-loader
            new NativeScriptWorkerPlugin(),
            ngCompilerPlugin,
            // Does IPC communication with the {N} CLI to notify events when running in watch mode.
            new nsWebpack.WatchStateLoggerPlugin(),
        ],
    };


    if (report) {
        // Generate report files for bundles content
        config.plugins.push(new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
            analyzerMode: "static",
            openAnalyzer: false,
            generateStatsFile: true,
            reportFilename: resolve(projectRoot, "report", `report.html`),
            statsFilename: resolve(projectRoot, "report", `stats.json`),
        }));
    }

    if (snapshot) {
        config.plugins.push(new nsWebpack.NativeScriptSnapshotPlugin({
            chunk: "vendor",
            angular: true,
            requireModules: [
                "reflect-metadata",
                "@angular/platform-browser",
                "@angular/core",
                "@angular/common",
                "@angular/router",
                "nativescript-angular/platform-static",
                "nativescript-angular/router",
            ],
            projectRoot,
            webpackConfig: config,
        }));
    }

    if (hmr) {
        config.plugins.push(new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin());
    }

    return config;
};
```

**app-routing.module.ts**:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "nativescript-angular/router";
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { TabsComponent } from "./home/tabs.component";
import { HomeComponent } from "./home/home-tab/home.component";
import { CategoriesComponent } from "./home/categories-tab/categories.component";
import { InfoComponent } from "./home/info-tab/info.component";
import { LocationsComponent } from "./home/locations-tab/locations.component";
import { AccountComponent } from "./home/account-tab/account.component";
export const COMPONENTS = [TabsComponent, HomeComponent, CategoriesComponent, InfoComponent, LocationsComponent, AccountComponent];

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    redirectTo: "/home",
    pathMatch: "full"
  },
  {
    path: "home",
    loadChildren: "./home/home.module#HomeModule"
  },
  {
    path: "products",
    loadChildren: "./products/products.module#ProductsModule"
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**app.module.ts**:

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { CoreModule } from "./core/core.module";
import { SharedModule } from "./shared/shared.module";
import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
//import { HomeModule } from "./home/home.module";
import { NativeScriptCommonModule } from "nativescript-angular/common";
import { TNSFrescoModule } from "nativescript-fresco/angular";
import * as applicationModule from "tns-core-modules/application";
import * as frescoModule from "nativescript-fresco";
declare var GMSServices: any;
if (applicationModule.android) {
  applicationModule.on("launch", () => {
    frescoModule.initialize();
  });
} else {
  GMSServices.provideAPIKey("XXXXXXX");
}

// Uncomment and add to NgModule imports if you need to use two-way binding
// import { NativeScriptFormsModule } from "nativescript-angular/forms";

// Uncomment and add to NgModule imports if you need to use the HttpClient wrapper
// import { NativeScriptHttpClientModule } from "nativescript-angular/http-client";

@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  imports: [NativeScriptCommonModule, CoreModule, SharedModule, TNSFrescoModule, AppRoutingModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  providers: [],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})
/*
Pass your application module to the bootstrapModule function located in main.ts to start your app
*/
export class AppModule {}
```

**when i try to build the project using this command** :

```
tns build android --bundle --env.aot --env.uglify
```

**it does  return this error**:

```
ERROR in ../$$_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Volumes/Work/mobile/nativescript/xxxx/src/app/home/home.module.ngfactory.js' in '/Volumes/Work/mobile/nativescript/xxxx/$$_lazy_route_resource'
 @ ../$$_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object ./home/home.module.ngfactory
 @ ../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js
 @ ./app/app.module.ts
 @ ./main.ts

ERROR in ../$$_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Volumes/Work/mobile/nativescript/xxxx/src/app/products/products.module.ngfactory.js' in '/Volumes/Work/mobile/nativescript/xxxx/$$_lazy_route_resource'
 @ ../$$_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object ./products/products.module.ngfactory
 @ ../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js
 @ ./app/app.module.ts
 @ ./main.ts

Executing webpack failed with exit code 2.
```

Comment: Do you have a sample Github repo where this issue can be reproduced?

Answer (score 0):

it was just a problem with a function i passed 1 param for it but expected 2 param that's why the build failed.